# setValue:forKey: Sets All Values for Specified Index

Tags: ios, nsmutablearray, nsmutabledictionary

I know this is going to be really basic, but I can't seem to figure it out.

I have an `NSMutableArray` with two indexes, each with an `NSMutableDictionary` with a few values. I want to change one value in one index with `[[anArray objectAtIndex:index] setValue:newValue forKey:someKey];` but this changes the value for that key in all indexes. I'm not sure what is going on.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Sounds like you have constructed your array incorrectly by adding the same dictionary over-and-over to the array.

Comment: I have added that dictionary more than once. I need those values for multiple indexes. That's not the way to do it?

Comment: No, I cannot see the point of adding the same dictionary to an array more than once.  Create a new dictionary for each element in the array.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by "Create a new dictionary for each element in the array." Could you explain?

Comment: Basically the same answer I gave to this question about an hour ago :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15442345/nsmutablearray-is-not-storing-data-properly-into-the-loop/15442383#15442383

Comment: That's what did it!! Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No issues with your code `[[anArray objectAtIndex:index] setValue:newValue forKey:someKey];`

You should add the `NSMutableDictionary` like this

```
NSMutableArray *myArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

NSMutableDictionary *dict1 = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"dict1value1", @"key1", @"dict1value2", @"key2", nil];


[myArray addObject:[dict1 copy]];

[myArray addObject:dict1];

[[myArray objectAtIndex:1] setValue:@"NEW VALUE" forKey:@"key2"];

NSLog(@"%@",[myArray objectAtIndex:0]);
NSLog(@"%@",[myArray objectAtIndex:1]);
```

or

```
   NSMutableArray *myArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    NSMutableDictionary *dict1 = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"dict1value1", @"key1", @"dict1value2", @"key2", nil];

    NSMutableDictionary *dict2 = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"dict2value1", @"key1", @"dict2value2", @"key2", nil];

    [myArray addObject:dict1];

    [myArray addObject:dict2];

    [[myArray objectAtIndex:1] setValue:@"NEW VALUE" forKey:@"key2"];

    NSLog(@"%@",[myArray objectAtIndex:0]);
    NSLog(@"%@",[myArray objectAtIndex:1]);
```

**Output**

```
{
    key1 = dict1value1;
    key2 = dict1value2;
}

{
    key1 = dict1value1;
    key2 = "NEW VALUE";
}
```

Comment: I used a 'for' loop which added the dictionary using `addObject:dict.mutablecopy` but generally the same approach. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**COPY it before adding the dict**

dont add it N times because you will have an array with N pointers to the same dictionary

```
id d1 = @{.....}.mutableCopy;
id d2 = d1.mutableCopy;

NSArray *array = @[d1,d2];
```

THEN edit the keys / values independently using setValueForKey or so